# magento javascript skin path admin vs frontend in layout

Tags: magento

I have a module that has JS I want to use in both the admin and frontend side.  I currently have my JS in my frontend skin folder

```
skin/frontend/default/default/module/js/myfile.js
```

if I need to utilize this JS file in both the frontend and admin side, is this the best spot for it?  or should I put this inside the root JS folder?

when I try to add a skin_js item in a layout file, the admin is not pulling the right path.

This is the entry I put in both the admin and frontend files.  is there a better way to do it? or something that I'm missing?

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>module/js/myfile.js</name></action>
```

**Admin url I get back:**

`http://www.site.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/module/js/myfile.js`

**Frontend url I get back:**

`http://www.site.com/skin/frontend/default/default/module/js/myfile.js`

Answer (score 0):

i usually keep my js files in `js/lib` so i can access it from any location.